# PHP split a very big number

Tags: php, split, numbers

I used a number below in my code:

```
$MyString = '06887558108616348​33464996​60139294';
```

When i'm trying to split MyString into a same pieces for example: 06887558, 10861634 so on... using substr or str_split that gives me:

```
06887558, 10861634, 8â€‹3346, 4996â€‹6, 0139294
```

Someone explain why this happend?!?

The Code what I have tried

```
$MyNewString; $n = 8; // How many you want before seperation 
$MyNewString = substr($MyString,0,$n); 
$i = $n; 
while ($i < strlen($MyString)) { 
    $MyNewString .= '-'; // Seperator Character 
    $MyNewString .= substr($MyString,$i,$n); 
    $i = $i + $n; 
} 
echo $MyNewString;
```

Comment: Please provide the exact, complete, minimal code necessary to reproduce this exact problem.

Comment: show your code what you have tried

Comment: There is nothing but $MyString which i'm deciding to split.

Comment: $MyNewString;
        $n = 8;
        $MyNewString = substr($MyString,0,$n); 
        $i = $n;
        while ($i < strlen($MyString)) {
        $MyNewString .= '-'; 
        $MyNewString .= substr($MyString,$i,$n);
        $i = $i + $n;
        }
        echo $MyNewString

Comment: Also used str_split($MyString,7) to split into 8 parts but there was no different.

Comment: Your string contain special characters. copy your string and paste it in editor, it will display `?` like characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add charset utf-8

add this code

```
echo '<meta charset="UTF-8">';
```

see the result I have tried

[image]

Comment: It's better to use `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: @Jack you are right. I just give one of the solution. not best solution

Comment: Also, this only masks the problem; the real issue is with the string contents which should be cleaned up to only contain numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_string = implode(', ', str_split($n, 8));
echo $new_string;
```

If you're getting funny characters in the result, then they must have been in the original string. `substr` and `str_split` don't add anything.

Comment: that brings the same result in browser:06887558, 10861634, 8â€‹3346, 4996â€‹6, 0139294

Comment: Read the last line of my answer.

Comment: I copied your $MyString and print it. It gives '06887558108616348â€‹33464996â€‹6013929406887558'. So, your string have some characters. Please avoid it